# How to make crystal report viewer work in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, browser, report, viewer

My crystal report work pretty fine in Fire Fox, but for google chrome and internet explorer its will only show a blank page.

1.Fire Fox
[image]

2.Internet Explorer, Google Chrome
[image]

I am using visual studio 2013, IIS, Crystal Report 13.

All the screen shoot is after I publish to local host, because its not working(showing blank page) when only browse from visual studio.

Your comment and help are much appreciated!!!

Comment: Is the sourcecode same for all browsers?

Comment: Yes.. I publish to localhost only open the file

Comment: I suggest you to inspect the document first. For any 404 errors or any javascript errors at Chrome or IE.